# How to change crystal report object font fit text view

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to change the font size of an object to fit the text view in the crystal report with c#

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change it to a certain fixed size, just go to format field and choose the font size.

If you're trying to change the size based on some condition, use this:

1. Click on the font tab.
2. Click on the formula button next to size.
3. Put your conditional formula there as:

"if condition then fontsize# else fontsize#"

Example:

```
if {tbl.color}="blue" then 2 else 3
```

Comment: I need to change font size according text size to fit the space assigned to it in the design

Comment: You can use `Len(str)` to get the characters count of the string and make the condition based on it.